# What does Ginga, Gingka or Ginkga mean?

Tags: slang, offensive-language, racism

I have been told that it's a racist derogatory term.

Comment: I've never heard this one. Are you sure it's English?

Comment: Welcome to the EL&U website!  Please [visit this link](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to take tour and learn about asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

If someone told you it is a racist derogatory term, they are probably referring to red-haired-individuals.

In some countries like the UK, ginga (pronnounced jin-ja, not gin-ga) is a slang form of "Ginger".

See Urban Dictionary [Ginga](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ginga)

> Slang U.K Ginger

See Wikipedia [Red Hair - Modern-day discrimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair#Modern-day_discrimination)

> In British English, the words "ginger" or "ginga" are sometimes used
>   to describe red-headed people (and are at times considered insulting)

Some other countries from English speaking history like Australia, has similar slang but it's "Ranga" as in "Orangatang" implying the orange/red hair the animals have.

See Urban Dictionary [Ranga](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ranga)

> a person who has red or orange hair

Comment: I upvoted you but ELU really requires supporting references and links. Please add, when you can. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: @LittleEva ok, I added references, but is Urban Dictionary even remotely a valid source? I suppose for slang it must be.

Comment: The UD is great for some definitions, not so much for others. Best to cross-reference. Tip: your links will look better on the page if you format thus - **[NAME of SOURCE](URL)**.

Comment: Also, ELU strongly recommends (insists, actually) we include our citations "in text" at some appropriate place in your answer because a bare [link] is subject to link "rot" and will then be of little avail to any reader. So, foe example, I will write; see, Urban Dictionary "ginga" [LINK](URL).

Comment: @LittleEva ok that last comment is a bit confusing, can you confirm I did it ok?

Comment: Yeah, Renny, I misspoke, here's my "current" method: see, Urban Dictionary ["**ginga**"](URL). Sorry.  :-)